# Output array to csv in Ruby applying dump to string values

Tags: ruby, csv

I have an array containing nested arrays. Each nested array contains the 'line' for a csv file I want to create. The problem is that the nested array contains strings with a lot of escape characters (\n\t).

I can output into the console what I want correctly with this :

```
printCollection.each do |collection|
    collection.each do |individualLine|
        print individualLine.dump
    end
end
```

But I can't figure out what the equivalent is when writing into the csv file:

```
printCollection.each do |collection|
    file << recordRow # what goes here?
end
```

If I try to nest another each iteration inside the csv like the console output then I will get incorrect formating where every record is set to a new line.

UPDATE:
Solved this by using regex instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  We need to know what (a sample is fine) of what's in printCollection.

Comment: Anthony, I'll follow up with Wikiti's answer, if that doesn't work work me, I'll update my question with additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Unless for homework or learning, you shouldn't be reinventing the wheel; save yourself a lot of trouble and try using the built-in [CSV class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html):

```
CSV.generate do |csv|
  printCollection.each do |collection|
    csv << collection
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried to apply that structure into my code, but I still got the line breaks applied to the text and not written out.